# JSON string cannot Deserialize using Newtonsoft.Json C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, webforms, json.net

I have a Xamarin forms app which contains a webview. I am trying to post a form using that webview to the server side asp.net aspx page. I first send those data to the inputs in local html file inside my app using **EvaluateJavaScriptAsync**. Data submited to the html file without no issue. 
I have a list which I convert it to json string from my app side before pass to the html file and it pass correctly. Then from submit button I post those data to the server side aspx page from the local html. Data submitted successfully but if I post that json string then from server side gives me an error(exception).

Exception...

```
JsonReaderException Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: o. Path'', line 1, position 1
```

Xamarin side...

Object class.

```
public class PaymentData
    {
        public string access_key { get; set; }
        public string profile_id { get; set; }
        public string transaction_uuid { get; set; }
        public string signed_field_names { get; set; }
        public string unsigned_field_names { get; set; }
        public string signed_date_time { get; set; }
        public string locale { get; set; }
        public string transaction_type { get; set; }
        public string reference_number { get; set; }
        public string currency { get; set; }
        public string bill_to_forename { get; set; }
        public string bill_to_surname { get; set; }
        public string bill_to_email { get; set; }
        public string bill_to_address_line1 { get; set; }
        public string bill_to_address_state { get; set; }
        public string bill_to_address_country { get; set; }
        public string bill_to_address_city { get; set; }
        public string polNum { get; set; }
        public string userName { get; set; }
        public string amount { get; set; }
        public double duesTotal { get; set; }
        public double addtAmt { get; set; }
        public double deposits { get; set; }
        public double duesPaid { get; set; }
        public List<DueData> lifeDueData { get; set; }

    }

public class DueData
    {
        public string paidDue { get; set; }
        public double premium { get; set; }
        public double lateFee { get; set; }
    }
```

After adding data, I converted object to json string

```
PaymentData lData = new PaymentData();   
string jsonOutput = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lData);
```

HTML file...

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function updatetextonwebview(jSonOgj) {

            var plots = JSON.parse(jSonOgj);

            document.getElementById("textElement1").value = plots.access_key;
            document.getElementById("textElement2").value = plots.profile_id;
            document.getElementById("textElement3").value = plots.transaction_uuid;
            document.getElementById("textElement4").value = plots.signed_field_names;
            ...........................
            document.getElementById("textElement23").value = plots.deposits;
            document.getElementById("textElement24").value = plots.duesPaid;
            document.getElementById("textElement25").value = plots.lifeDueData;

            return plots.lifeDueData;

        }
    </script>

</head>
<body align="center">

    <div class="container card">

    <form id="payment_form" action="//....payment_confirmation_life.aspx" method="post">

        <input type="hidden" class="hiddeninput" hidden="hidden" id="textElement1" name="access_key">
        <input type="hidden" class="hiddeninput" hidden="hidden" id="textElement2" name="profile_id">
        <input type="hidden" class="hiddeninput" hidden="hidden" id="textElement3" name="transaction_uuid">
        <input type="hidden" class="hiddeninput" hidden="hidden" id="textElement4" name="signed_field_names">
        ........................
        <input type="hidden" class="hiddeninput" hidden="hidden" id="textElement20" name="userName">
        <input type="hidden" class="hiddeninput" hidden="hidden" id="textElement21" name="duesTotal">
        <input type="hidden" class="hiddeninput" hidden="hidden" id="textElement22" name="addtAmt">
        <input type="hidden" class="hiddeninput" hidden="hidden" id="textElement23" name="deposits">
        <input type="hidden" class="hiddeninput" hidden="hidden" id="textElement24" name="duesPaid">
        <input type="hidden" class="hiddeninput" hidden="hidden" id="textElement25" name="lifeDueData">

        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Proceed" />

    </form>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

payment_confirmation_life.aspx code behind...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Request.Form.Count > 0)
        {

            if (Request.Form["lifeDueData"] != null)
            {

            string demadData = Request.Form["lifeDueData"].ToString().Trim();

            List<DueData> duelist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DueData>>(demadData);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Exception occurs in DeserializeObject line**

JSON...

```
[{"lateFee":250,"paidDue":"2020/01","premium":11896}]
```

Comment: what is the value of `demadData` before the deserialization?

Comment: Use your debugger in the asp.net app to check the value of `demadData` after the `string demadData = Request.Form["lifeDueData"].ToString().Trim();` command has executed. Check that it matches exactly what you expect.

Comment: P.S. why are you using an aspx page as the backend for this Xamarin app? Web API is likely to be a more suitable solution, and easier to work with.

Comment: sorry for the delay. i had to speak with server admin to get the response. acctually **demadData  = [object Object]**. Then I put a console.log inside my local html file to check what value i get for the input filed . It is also **[object Object]**. But from javascript it return correct json string to xamarin side

Comment: Inside javascript **plots.lifeDueData** value is *[object Object]*.

Comment: @ADyson because our payment gateway has developed using asp.net

Comment: You probably need to write `document.getElementById("textElement25").value = JSON.stringify(plots.lifeDueData);` when populating the field. Otherwise Javascript will just write the default string value of that object/array into the field, which is `[Object object]` as you are seeing.

Comment: You might need to reform the data to start with an object: `{ "DueData": [ { "lateFee":250,"paidDue":"2020/01","premium":11896 } ] }`.